# Adding two numbers without using operators

Tags: c

I found this following code for addition of two numbers without using the `+` operator.

code to add 3 and 4:

```
printf("%d",printf("%*c%*c",3,' ',4,' '));
```

Now `printf()` returns the number of characters in the result
and `%*c` ignores the next character that it encounters. But still, I am not able to understand this code. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That code has also some significant side-effect.

Comment: only side effect I know is that it shifts the output according to the number of spaces it gets as input. anything else ?

Comment: But that side-effect is a major one. You can't simply tell that it is a weird way to do an addition.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`printf("%*c", n, c)` prints the character `c`, `n` times. So the code prints 3 spaces followed by 4 spaces, and `printf` returns the number of characters printed, which is obviously 3 + 4, completing the problem.

Comment: Actually it prints the character `c` right-justified on a field width of `n`, padded with spaces. (Not padded with copies of `c` as your answer suggests)

Answer (score 5):

The inner `printf` outputs 3 then 4 spaces and returns the number of characters, which is 7, and the outer `printf` is printing that result.

Answer (score 1):

I am adding this answer to specify the rules of the standard.

Here this is utilizing the return value of `printf`. Respectively `3-1` spaces(`' '`) and then again space (as you specified) and  `4-1` spaces and then again 1 space is being printed. And then the total number of characters written is returned. That is how the sum is being done.

I just remember this rule

```
printf("%*c",X,C) prints the char C in a field of size X
```

All these behavior is explained in C11 Standard.

From standard  **[§7.21.6.1p4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p4)**

> An optional minimum field width. ***If the converted value has fewer
>   characters than the field width, it is padded with spaces (by default)***
>   on the left (or right, if the left adjustment flag, described later,
>   has been given) to the field width. *The field width takes the form of
>   an asterisk `*` (described later) or a nonnegative decimal integer.*

And in the same section  **[§7.21.6.1p5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p5)**

> As noted above, ***a field width, or precision, or both, may be
>   indicated by an asterisk. In this case, an int argument supplies the
>   field width or precision***

At last [**§7.21.6.1.p14**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p14)

> ***The `fprintf` function returns the number of characters transmitted***, or
>   a negative value if an output or encoding error occurred.

---

To clear your idea this example will be good enough (I am using `%d` here so that you get the idea of the field).

If `x = 10` and `y=2` then it will be

```
printf("%*d%*d",  x, x,  y, y);
```

More clearly

```
| | | | | | | | |1|0| |2|
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 \ \
                      11 12

That's how 12 characters are printed.
```