# How to add two variables without using a '+' operator?

Tags: c

I was asked this question in an interview:

> How to add two variables without using a '+' operator?

The interviewer asked me and I could not answer, even though I am a good C programmer!

Comment: Maybe `x - (- y)` ?

Comment: Voting to close a C question as a duplicate of a C# question is not correct.

Comment: @coredump did the same thing but he insisted me not to do that !!

Comment: @2501 but the algorithm doesn't change

Comment: @KamiKaze Language tags are relevant and must match.

Comment: @Anjaneyulu Unfortunately, this position required you to be able to perform mind reading.

Comment: @Matt That is undefined behaviour, as it has there is unsequenced side-effects on variables that are read on multiple subexpressions. Or to put it short: your expression is broken and illegal.

Comment: For floating point numbers: `log(exp(x) * exp(y))`

Comment: See: [sum (adding 2 numbers ) without plus operator](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17450959/253056) and [Adding two numbers without using operators](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12331328/253056)

Answer (score 3):

Using **bitwise** operators you can add two numbers. Try below:

```
   int Sum(int a, int b)
    {
        // Iterate till there is no carry  
        while (b != 0)
        {
            // now carry contains common set bits of a and b
            int carry = a & b;  

            // Sum of bits of a and b where at least one of the bits is not set
            a = a ^ b; 

            // Carry is shifted by one so that adding it to a gives the required sum
           b = carry << 1;
        }
        return a;
    }
```

Using **Increment and decrement** operators you can add two numbers.
The other way may be like:

```
int Sum(int a, int b)
{
    // Iterate till there b becomes zero
    while (b--)
    {
        a++;
    }
    return a;
}
```